# How do you connect to a remote database with SQLTALK?

Tags: sql-server

How do you connect to a remote database with SQLTALK?

EDIT:
I was going to add a SQLTALK tag but I'm not cool enough again. So... could someone re-tag this question? Thanks Marc_s for the tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked for me for my SQL Server:
Create an ODBC
edit the SQL.ini

```
[win32client.dll]
comdll=sqlodb32

[ODBCRTR]
remotedbname=Alias,DSN=NameOfYourODBC
```

Then in SQLTalk open the connection dialog and type the Alias into the database field. Then enter your credentials and press Connect.

Connecting to Oracle is similar, add these lines:

```
[ORAGTWY]
remotedbname=Alias,@TNS_name
longbuffer=900000
substitute=SYSSQL.,
fetchrow=100
maperror=off


[win32client.dll]
comdll=sqlora32
```

I hope this helps someone else out.